# Check if input is int before adding to list

Tags: java, arraylist, int

I'm trying to split an inputted number into its digits by adding each digit to an Integer list. I have to enter a non-integer in order to stop the Scanner from looking for more integers. However, when I enter a non-integer I always get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
```

I know that this comes from the fact that I'm expecting an int but getting another type of input, but I don't know why that's happening. Shouldn't the `if(inputtedText.hasNextInt())` keep this from happening?

```
List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Scanner inputtedText = new Scanner(System.in);

String stringOfInputtedNumber = "";
while(true) {
    if(inputtedText.hasNextInt()) {
        stringOfInputtedNumber += inputtedText.nextInt();
//      digits.add(inputtedText.nextInt());
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to specify that the commented out line is the one that causes the problem.

Comment: Yes, `hasNextInt()` should prevent `InputMismatchException`, and it does. What *specifically* are you typing to cause *that* error with *that* code? --- Are you *sure* you're running *that* code?

Comment: it looks fine. try to compile file again then run it.

Comment: I'm using the Eclipse IDE, and just testing it in the IDE without actually exporting it. Could that be the problem? @user3091574

Comment: @Andreas I took another look at the code and realized that I was using nextInt() thinking it'd just return a since character instead of the entire thing. The way the input will be setup I don't need that, so I fixed it and now it's working. Thanks!

Comment: @user3091574 I took another look at the code and realized that I was using nextInt() thinking it'd just return a since character instead of the entire thing. The way the input will be setup I don't need that, so I fixed it and now it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your file,recompile it and try running it again.
I tried your code on my machine and it works just as expected 
No inputMismatch exception and no need for try block

Comment: I took another look at the code and realized that I was using nextInt() thinking it'd just return a since character instead of the entire thing. The way the input will be setup I don't need that, so I fixed it and now it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Yes, `hasNextInt()` can fix that but you should also remember of closing IO classes such as Scanner.

```
    List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    try (Scanner inputtedText = new Scanner("123123123A")) {
        String stringOfInputtedNumber = "";
        while (true) {
            if (inputtedText.hasNextInt()) {
                stringOfInputtedNumber += inputtedText.nextInt();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
    System.out.println(stringOfInputtedNumber);
```

It can be done using try-with-resources